# Convert folder with multipage page tiff files to pdf with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a folder with multiple page tiff files to pdf.

I can separately convert each file with commandline code:

"convert name.tif - compress jpeg name.pdf"

The original tif is 50mB and the pdf is 1,3mB and that is fine, because is it will be used to put on a wordpress website.

Now, how can I convert the whole folder with tifs to pdfs.

I also tried code with magick mogrify:

"magick mogrify -format pdf *.tif"

That works, but then the pdf is also 50mB.

So I need a combination of the two?

Comment: add the -compress jpeg command to your mogrify `magick mogrify -format pdf -compress jpeg *.tif`

Comment: Thank you, fmw42, that did the job. Can someone help me to put this in an bat file? I want to go to the folder whith the tifs and then do the mogrify. I'm not fimiliar with bat files and how to make and run them.

Comment: What I also want to do: after mogrify put the pdfs in another folder.

Comment: You can add `-path path_to_new_folder` in mogrify to send the results to a new directory. The folder must exist. ImageMagick will not create a new folder in mogrify. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: Anywhere after mogrify and before *.tif. I usually add it right after mogrify. But you can put it between pdf and -compress, if you want.